# powershell storing multiple returns as unique variables

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, exchange-online

I have run into a nasty little issue I cannot figure out how to solve.  When I run:

```
Get-Mailbox -softdeletedmailbox -identity blahblah@itsasecret.edu | fl *exchangeguid*
```

I get multiple results on multiple lines:

```
ExchangeGuid : aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa

ExchangeGuid : bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb
```

and when I run

```
Get-Mailbox blahblah@itsasecret.edu | fl *exchangeguid*
```

I get a single result:

```
ExchangeGuid : cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc
```

Basically I have a broken O365 mailbox that has 2 old mailbox guids and 1 new one all for the same user.  How can I script running the get-mailbox softdelete, have it store each of the returned old guids (aaa and bbb) as separate variables, store the new guid (ccc) as a variable, and then run:

```
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -sourcemailbox $VariableA -targetmailbox $VariableC -AllowLegacyDNMismatch

New-MailboxRestoreRequest -sourcemailbox $VariableB -targetmailbox $VariableC -AllowLegacyDNMismatch
```

I have been doing this by hand copying/pasting the lines in powershell, but I now have to do this on several thousand accounts and one at a time manual isn't cutting it anymore.

Any thoughts are extremely welcome!

I have tried lots of random stuff I've seen online, but none have been able to separate the broken guids into different variables that I can then use.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and format your code properly using a [code block]? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know it’s *definitely* returning exactly 2 mailboxes *every* time you can use decomposition to assign individual items in the return value to multiple variables - e.g. ```$variableA, $variableB = Get-Mailbox -softdeletedmailbox …``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.4#assigning-multiple-variables. If you’re not sure how many will be returned you can assign the return value to an array variable and inspect its length - ```$result = @(Get-Mailbox …); if( $result.Length -eq 2 ) { … }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you really need to assign the GUIDs to different variables, might be as simple as enumerating each GUID for the *soft deleted mailboxes* and passing it as argument for `New-MailboxRestoreRequest`:

```bash
$identity = 'blahblah@itsasecret.edu'
$targetMbx = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $identity).ExchangeGuid
(Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox -Identity $identity).ExchangeGuid | ForEach-Object {
    $newMailboxRestoreRequestSplat = @{
        SourceMailbox         = $_
        TargetMailbox         = $targetMbx
        AllowLegacyDNMismatch = $true
    }
    New-MailboxRestoreRequest @newMailboxRestoreRequestSplat
}
```

Also looking at the description of the [`-TargetMailbox` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboxrestorerequest?view=exchange-ps#-targetmailbox) the first call of `Get-Mailbox -Identity $identity` might not be needed since the parameter can take the email address as argument:

> The TargetMailbox parameter specifies the GUID of the target mailbox **or mail user** where you want to restore content to. The target mailbox or mail user needs to exist before you can run this command successfully.

So, it is possible that the code could be reduced to:

```bash
$identity = 'blahblah@itsasecret.edu'
(Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox -Identity $identity).ExchangeGuid | ForEach-Object {
    $newMailboxRestoreRequestSplat = @{
        SourceMailbox         = $_
        TargetMailbox         = $identity
        AllowLegacyDNMismatch = $true
    }
    New-MailboxRestoreRequest @newMailboxRestoreRequestSplat
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ and exactly how I had hoped. I so love this place.

Comment: @Dazormiq glad it was helpful! ;)